# Spring security does not work on server (google appengine)

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a simple spring project which works locally. The urls are intercepted by spring security but when I upload the same to google appengine server, the security fails to work and the assciated method is instead executed.

```
public class SpringSecutiryInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
   // Do nothing. This initializes the security chain.
}


public class SpringMvcInitializer 
       extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  Environment env;
  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {

    String databaseName = env.getProperty("jdbc.databaseName");
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select username,password,enabled from user where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "SELECT user.username, role.role FROM (" + databaseName
                + ".user_role as role JOIN " + databaseName
                + ".user as user ON"
                + " role.auth_id = user.auth_id) where user.username=?");
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.djw" })
public class AppConfig {
    // configure different beans
}
```

appengine-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <!-- Fill in the app name and version -->
  <application>project-name-removed</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <!-- Configure serving/caching of GWT files -->
  <static-files>
    <include path="**" />

    <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
    <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />

    <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
    <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
  </static-files>

  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/appengine_logging.properties"/>
    <property name="spring.profiles.active" value="prod"/>
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <!-- Declare a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as usual -->
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <!-- Configure DispatcherServlet to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
           instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
          <param-value>
              org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
          </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <!-- Again, config locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
           and fully-qualified @Configuration classes -->
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>com.djw.config.AppConfig</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <!-- map all requests for / to the dispatcher servlet -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

With these, any url I try to open is intercepted by spring for username and password. But on my server, it would just let the requests pass. why would this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I learn from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869306/implement-spring-security-on-google-app-engine) is that currently Google App Engine supports up to servlet version 2.5, and `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` requires servlet version 3.0. So, you have to use xml to config your settings.