# Implement spring security on google app engine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-security

I'm trying to integrate the spring security on google app engine. But it doesn't work properly. I wang to authenticate user when they try to access `index` page, and redirect them to `login` page. But now I can visit the `index` page directly.

I followed [spring.io](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html) website tutorial and [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/) tutorial.

here are part of my pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

`AppConfig` class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
//@ComponentScan({ "com.example.web.*" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.web" })
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

`SecurityConfig` class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/account/login");
    }
}
```

`SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` class

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

`WebApplicationInitializer` class

```
public class WebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

`AccountController` class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Index(Model model) {

        return "login";
    }
}
```

`HomeController` class

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String Index(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("x", 1);
    model.addAttribute("y", 2);
    model.addAttribute("z", 3);

    return "index";
}
```

`index.jsp` page

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
.....
```

`login.jsp` page

```
<%@page session="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

What I want to achieve now is to redirect unauthenticated user to login page.
But now it does not work, I can visit home page directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebApplicationInitializer` requires Servlet 3.0, but Appengine supports only Servlet 2.5. So you have to use plain XML based config, at least for initialization. And configure Spring filter/servlet in `web.xml` manually.

You need to put into `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>path.to.AppConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and into `spring-security.xml`:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<beans:bean class="path.to.SecurityConfig"/>
```

Basically it's all standard stuff from pre-servlet 3.0 time, and you could use any tutorial (or old docs) based on servlet 2.4 or 2.5, it will work on Appengine.

PS also you could vote for Servlet 3.0 support at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091

Comment: thank you a lot, I'll try now. but gae really gave me a lot of headache. do you use gae a lot? in what use case?

Comment: using it a lot, yes. great platform. but have some barriers to entry, many differences compared to traditional hosting, a lot of stuff to learn, etc.

Comment: how do you think it compared to aws?

Comment: different things. you could compare Google Compute Engine or Container Engine to AWS. I think it have superior technologies and more developer friendly, and much easier to make scalable apps (everything just focused on it)

Comment: can i invite you to see this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891610