# spring security custom login page return 404

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, spring-security

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220556/how-to-implement-custom-authentication-in-spring-security-3) to set up my custom login page with spring security.The problem is when access `/`, it will redirect to `/account/login`, and this `/account/login` will return 404 `Error: NOT_FOUND`. How to fix this issue.

`spring-security.xml` file

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/account/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="email"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean name="customUserDetailsService" class="com.example.web.CustomUserDetailsService">
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

`spring-servlet.xml` file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web.*" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

`CustomUserDetailsService` file

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        if (email == null || email.trim().equals("")) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid email address.");
        }

        try (Connection conn = Config.getConn()) {

            String query = "xxx";

            PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(query);

            stm.setString(1, email);

            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

            if (!rs.next()) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                        "User does not exist.");
            }

            if (rs.getBoolean("delete")) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User has been deleted.");
            }

            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils
                    .createAuthorityList("USER");

            String password = rs.getString("pass");

            UserDetails user = new User(email, password, true, true, true,
                    true, authorities);

            return user;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Unable to connect to database.");
    }
}
```

`AccountController` file

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Index(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

`HomeController` file

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Index(Model model) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

`web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myweb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myweb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.app.xxx.yyyService</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

log from google app engine

> ip.ip.ip.ip - - [05/Mar/2015:19:41:49 -0800] "GET /account/login HTTP/1.1" 404 204 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115
>   Safari/537.36" "xxx.appspot.com" ms=830 cpu_ms=606
>   cpm_usd=0.000023 instance=00c61bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx624e0fc
>   app_engine_release=1.9.18 trace_id=60de930xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbb7ab5

**EDIT**

The problem is inside servlet.xml, change `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web.*" />` to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web" />` and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you can access the login page directly.

In your web.xml see what url pattern you're using for the dispatcher.  Here's mine:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then, ensure that you can request /login.htm directly.

Once you get login working, change your spring-security.xml to append ".htm" onto your URLs.  So your fragment might look like this:

```
<form-login 
            login-page="/login.htm" 
            default-target-url="/welcome.htm" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error" 
            username-parameter="email"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.htm?logout" />
```

Comment: I can't access `/account/login` directly. and my url-pattern value is `/*`

Comment: Is your controller annotation getting scanned?  I see this in your config: <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web.*" />  I'm not sure what package contains your controller.

Comment: YES! THIS IS THE CAUSE. I make it work just now when you post this comments!!