# How to correctly define web.xml and java-based config for Spring Security at the same time

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-security, csrf, thymeleaf

My project was based completely on java-based configs. So instead of standart web.xml I had this:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
          rootContext.register(WebAppConfiguration.class);
          AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

          ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
          dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
          dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
```

That work just fine, and I was able to get csrf token in Thymeleaf template like that:

```
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

But now I need to deploy my project to Google App Engine, and it requires to have web.xml otherwise it even doesn't start.
I added web.xml, and remove the java config above :

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.demshin.medpro.configuration.WebAppConfiguration</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And when I try to open my app's url, I get an exception:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
>   evaluating SpringEL expression: "_csrf.token"

As I think, the problem is in corrupted filter chain.
But if I add this to web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

instead of this java config:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(WebSecurityConfiguration.class);
    }
}
```

, the problem is still there though the trace is a bit different.

So how this can be cured? Maybe there is a way to get rid of web.xml on Google App Engine?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869306/implement-spring-security-on-google-app-engine).
The problem is that WebApplicationInitializer requires Servlet 3.0, but Appengine supports only Servlet 2.5. So we have to use plain XML based config, at least for initialization. And configure Spring filter/servlet in web.xml manually.
Unfortunately I failed to make it work without completely moving spring configuration to xml, just adding spring-security.xml didn't work.

We can also vote for Servlet 3.0 support [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3091), but it seems Google doesn't have any plans to add it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

What if you keep the java config and then create an empty web.xml e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

</web-app>
```